# Is there an ideal size for executable modules on Windows?

Tags: windows, dll, operating-system, executable

I've been taking note of the .exe file size of many applications.

I saw that Visual Studio 2005 has an .exe size of 453KB, and VS2008 of 1.04MB because they divide the application into many parts (.exe + many .dll files).

I saw also that MS Outlook has a very large .exe file (11.8MB) while MS Word is very small (398KB)!

After pondering the things that I had seen, I was left with these questions:

1. Is there an advantage to having a small .exe, even if the final size of the application (all DLLs loaded) is much larger?
2. And if so, at what size is it good to begin breaking up an application into separate modules?

Comment: Size is generally pretty irrelevant these days - unless you create gigabyte sized EXEs! I tend to prefer self-contained EXE with everything in it - gives less options to forget something and cause problems

Comment: Thanks to all how closed the question.

Comment: Nominated for reopening. While perhaps not expressed as well as it could be, there is a useful question here: what are the pros and cons of splitting an application into multiple modules versus one monolithic executable?

Comment: Edited - it was phrased subjectively, but i suspect this was an unintentional error on the part of Wael. I doubt he really cares what our opinions are, unless we have solid facts to back them up with...

Comment: Nominated for reopening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A large executable probably has less less shared libraries (less re-usable code), meaning that the application probably is more memory intensive than an application using shared libraries. If you want a system with minimal memory footprint you want shared libraries.

A big exe is likely to be more self-contained, which might make it easier to keep a stable deployment.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, big size exe may mean you collect all the dependencies in single file so no dependency problem like [dll hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell) but every time you want to fix any thing in small module the user has to download this big exe!!!

On the other hand small exe it may mean you modularize your application to different modules so it is easy to maintain and upgrade these modules separately and user does not have to download the big chunk exe

Answer (score 2):

These articles:

> #### An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format
>
> [Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx), [Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx)

Seem to be a very nice summary of the file format the Windows executables (and DLLs) use.

As far as I have been able to see, the author nowhere mentions anything about whether a certain size for an executable is better than a smaller/bigger size.

So this *could* mean that the size of an executable doesn't really matter to Windows.

On the other hand, I *think* that when you open an executable in Windows, the file will be scanned by Virus Scanners (if any) prior to handing off the file to the OS for execution. So this *could* mean, that larger executable means longer startup time in the presence of a scanning application.

Comment: +1 for virus scanning. Also has to load the EXE into RAM so there will be slight delay when starting up.  I don't think you would want your EXE to be 20MB or higher.